# Apache ErrorDocument depends on browser language

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, errordocument

we would like to create a different language pages which depends on the browser language
however it doesn't pick up the fr and zh error page, 
does anyone know what did I miss ?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound_fr.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^zh [NC]
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound_zh.html

#RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !(^fr|^zh) [NC]
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
```

Comment: The `ErrorDocument` directive is not affected by the rewrite module. See [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html#multi-lang). With mod_rewrite it may be condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Answer (score 0):

as Deadooshka mentioned, 
the solution is :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^zh [NC]
RewriteRule ^/notfound.html$ /notfound_zh.html [P,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^/notfound.html$ /notfound_f.html [P,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently testing out something like the following code for my .htaccess. So far, it's working good:

```
<If "req('accept-language') =~ m#^fr#i">
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound_fr.html
</If>
<ElseIf "req('accept-language') =~ m#^zh#i">
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound_zh.html
</ElseIf>
<Else>
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
</Else>
```